# Making a Class Based on Arrays Enumerable in C#

Tags: c#, types, enumerable

Okay, I have made an earnest effort to understand this over the past hour or so.  So I am wondering if someone can explain this to me.

I'm trying to make a class in C# be Enumerable.  Specifically, I'm trying to make it work with a foreach loop.  I have a test going with a simple class, with takes in characters into the constructor.

```
EmployeeArray ArrayOfEmployees = new EmployeeArray('a','b','c');

foreach(char e in EmployeeArray) //Nope, can't do this!
{
Console.WriteLine(e);
}

//---Class Definition:---

class EmployeeArray
{
    private char[] Employees;
    public EmployeeChars(char[] e)
    {
        this.Employees = e;
    }
    //Now for my attempt at making it enumerable:
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(int i)
    {
        return this.Employees[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement `IEnumerable` for your class. But why not just make a `List<Employee>` instead of your own collection class?

Comment: What does it mean to implement IEnumerable?  This sounds like what I need to do.  (Because I want to figure this out, I want to be able to make my own collection classes!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you stick with a simple `List<>`. This is a generic collection structure that does all the heavy lifting for you. Really, it does not make sense to make your own IEnumerables until you fully understand how the system works.

First, change your class to it represents a single item:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //add additional properties
}
```

Then make a `List<Employee>` object

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "John Smith" });

foreach(Employee emp in employees)
    Console.WriteLine(emp.Name);
```

If you really do want to get into making your own IEnumerables, look at the [msdn page on them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx), which has a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this? And BTW you can't use the Class as the collection because it's a type. You need to use your declared variable to access it.

```
// You cant use EmployeeArray, instead use ArrayOfEmployees 
foreach(char e in **EmployeeArray**) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Anyway here's how i did it.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Collection collect = new Collection(new string[]{"LOL1","LOL2"});
            foreach (string col in collect)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(col + "\n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Collection : IEnumerable
    {
        private Collection(){}
        public string[] CollectedCollection { get; set; }
        public Collection(string[] ArrayCollection)
        {
            CollectedCollection = ArrayCollection;
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.CollectedCollection.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```